# How can I get the tags section on Finder sidebar on OS X 10.8.5?

Tags: macos, finder, finder-tag

Yesterday I reinstalled Snow Leopard because Yosemite is too heavy for my MacBook. How can I get the tags section on the Finder sidebar on OS X 10.8.5 like Mavericks or Yosemite?

Comment: Snow Leopard is 10.6. 10.8.5 is Mountain Lion. What version of OS X are you using exactly? (@Buscar Neither of these OSes support Finder tags)

Comment: thank you for your answer, my mac os version is 10.8.5 :)

Answer (score 1):

Finder tags were [introduced in Mavericks](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202754) (10.9).
They're not available in earlier versions of OS X.

Comment: but its not possible to add or tweak it?